# Where does this \r\n come from when I redirect STDOUT to a PTY in Perl?

Tags: perl, newline, tty, pty

With the following code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use IO::Pty;
use Data::Dump qw(pp);

my $pty = IO::Pty->new;
open *STDOUT, '>&', $pty->slave;

if ( my $pid = open *STDOUT, '|-' ) {
  # parent
  my $str = "foo\n";
  print {*STDERR} "parent [1]: ", pp($str), "\n";
  print {*STDOUT} $str;
  my $line = <$pty>;
  print {*STDERR} "parent [2]: ", pp($line), "\n";
} else {
  # child
  while (<>) {
    print {*STDERR} "child [1]: ", pp($_), "\n";
    s/foo/bar/;
    print {*STDERR} "child [2]: ", pp($_), "\n";
    print $_;
  } ## end while (<>)
  exit;
} ## end else [ if ( my $pid = open *STDOUT...)]
```

The output I get is:

```
parent [1]: "foo\n"
child [1]: "foo\n"
child [2]: "bar\n"
parent [2]: "bar\r\n"
```

But on the last line I expected to receive "bar\n". Also, I'm running Perl under Linux, so shouldn't this LF to CRLF nonsense be a non-issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\r` and `\n` are "control characters". What are "control characters" controlling? A typewriter. Well, it used to.

TTYs pre-date computers, going back to telegraphs. [TTY stands for teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter); literally a typewriter that types the output. As it was a typewriter, it needed to be told to slide (return) the print head (carriage) back to the first column of the page, and then advance the paper to the next line. `\r\n`.

Now that's baked into the tty protocol. Even though technology has moved on, it's still acting like it's talking to a typewriter.

See also [Why in the output of script (1) the newline is CR + LF (dos-style)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343332/86900)

Answer (score 6):

As indicated by the user Schwern, the problem was caused by the TTY itself.
I solved it by using the raw mode on the TTY.

```perl
$pty->slave->set_raw();
$pty->set_raw();
```